# Dokku Django - 404 Serving media files in production using storage plugin

Tags: django, dokku

I'm using the official ([Dokku storage plugin](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/advanced-usage/persistent-storage/)).

I have set up a simple Django project, with a model that has an ImageField. I can upload an image via the /admin, but when I try to access it after that, I get:

> The requested URL /media/some_media_file.png was not found on this server.

I know the file is there, because I've checked both the host and the container.

This is the storage mounted path:

```
dokku storage:list hellodjango
hellodjango volume bind-mounts:
    /var/lib/dokku/data/storage/hellodjango:/app/storage
```

These are my MEDIA settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/app/storage'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Dokku 0.7.2 and Django 1.10

Comment: You probably haven't configured Apache to serve the media files.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides I thought Dokku used Nginx. I've found some configuration related to this within Nginx config, but everytime I deploy to Dokku, Nginx config is reset.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Dokku; maybe you do use nginx alright. It still seems a problem with nginx configuration, but I'm not an expert here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a custom nginx.conf.sigil (documentation [here](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/configuration/nginx/#customizing-the-nginx-configuration)) where I added the following location:

```
location /media/  {
  alias /path/to/media/;
}
```